# gdb: how to set break point at main function or _start, when there's no debug info?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gdb, debug-symbols

In release version, when debugging, sometimes there's no debug information files, in this case, there's no convenient way to `b main` to start at main function.

So how can I let gdb break at the entry of the program, either the `_start` entry point or the C style `main` function?

Comment: use `readelf` to find the address of the entry point, and use `b *0x...`

Comment: I knew I'd already answered this before.  google for your question title found it as the second hit (after this question).  (But SO search didn't find it as easily, so I guess I won't downvote, and leave it as a signpost for future searches).

Comment: `_start` isn't specific to AT&T syntax.  `global _start` / `_start:` is what you do in NASM, as well, since it's the linker that looks for that symbol name by default.

Comment: One other possibility If you have dynamically linked against the _C_ runtime then you could break at __libc_start_main with `break __libc_start_main` this will get you reasonably close to the function `main` even if you didn't build with any debug information.

Comment: Any an addendum to Peter's answer (that he linked your question to) you don't need to use `objdump` or `readelf` to get the entry point. You can get GDB to display it with `info file` inside _GDB_

Comment: Also: You can and should include debug symbols in optimized binaries.  `-g` doesn't lead to slower code in any way.  You can even generate a core dump from a stripped binary, and debug it with the symbols from the unstripped binary.  (So you can ship stripped binaries and still make use of stack backtraces.  Or better, ship debug symbols as an optional package so people can create useful backtraces for you.  This is what Debian/Ubuntu packages like `xserver-xorg-core-dbg` are for.)